# Replace whole words using lists

Tags: python, regex

I have two lists of words (word_wrong and word_ok) and I need to replace words from list word_wrong with the correct word from word_ok. I need to search for whole words and case insensitive.

For just one word, I was using (and it was working):

```
fixed = re.sub(r'\bprot\b','profit', fixed, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I change to this:

```
def fix_fibase(texts):
    word_wrong= ['prot','protability','protable','protably','prots']
    word_ok =   ['profit','profitability','profitable','profitably','profits']
    fixed = texts
    for k in range(0,5):
        fixed = re.sub(r'\b' + word_wrong[k] + r'\b',word_ok[k], fixed, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The idea is to replace elements from the list word_wrong with the corresponding element in list word_ok, based on the element number. so prot->profit, protability->profitability, ...

As an example:

```
a="prots went up"
b=fix_fibase(a)
print(b)
```

output: "profs went up"
and it should be "profits went up"

but is not working... No error, but no replace made!

Any suggestion?

thanks a million!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you give an example ? What do you mean by 'but is not working' ?

Comment: @Gabip, please see the example for only one word. The idea is to replace, one element from a list to the corresponding element in the other list, based on the element number. so prot->profit, protability->profitability, ...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer no error, but also nothing change in the text...

Comment: @PauloAlves and return what? replace where? a text is provided to replace there?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including how you're calling `fix_fibase`, example input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Can you print `fixed` in the loop and post what is the output?

Comment: @Gabip the text is an input to the sentence. for example, "profs went up" should return "profits went up"

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function

Comment: `profs` is not defined `word_wrong`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, you just need to return `fixed`:

```
import re

def fix_fibase(texts):
    word_wrong= ['prot','protability','protable','protably','prots']
    word_ok =   ['profit','profitability','profitable','profitably','profits']
    fixed = texts
    for k in range(0,5):
        fixed = re.sub(r'\b' + word_wrong[k] + r'\b',word_ok[k], fixed, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return fixed


t = fix_fibase('prot is not evil')
print(t)
```

Output:

```
profit is not evil
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
def fix_fibase(text):
    word_wrong = ['prot', 'protability', 'protable', 'protably', 'prots']
    word_ok = ['profit', 'profitability', 'profitable', 'profitably', 'profits']
    dict_words = dict(
        zip(word_wrong, word_ok))  # it will create a dictionary with wrong word as a key and correct one as a value
    words = text.split(" ")
    replaced_text = " ".join([dict_words.get(word.lower(), word) for word in words])
    return replaced_text


print(fix_fibase("blah prot blah"))  # output: blah profit blah
```